Home brew foaming from bottle
My home brew beer frequently foams out of the bottle. Could old star san contribute to this?

The other "rob" answer does a good job of covering the usual suspects for "gushers" (bottles/cans that erupt when opened).
However, you asked specifically about "old Star San."
While Star San contains a foaming agent (to help ensure good coverage/contact time), that is definitely NOT the cause of your foaming.
When you use Star San, you dilute with water. My understanding is that a pH of less than 3.5 in the diluted solution will be effective. In practice, the diluted solution has a relatively short shelf life - on the order of hours to days. Is your "old Star San" in a diluted form? If so, it might well be ineffective.
In fact, I have noticed that diluted Star San fairly quickly (a couple of weeks) can become a source of nutrients for mold and other nasty stuff.
In it's undiluted form, Star San has a much longer shelf life. I think officially it expires three years after manufacture, but the Internet has lots of anecdotal evidence suggesting that it remains effective (even after opening) for 10+ years. However, the color definitely darkens significantly over a period of years.
One final note about Star San: It is a sanitizer, not a cleaner. Your equipment must already be clean in order for Star San to do it's job. It cannot kill stuff that is hiding under some goop or crust.

No, this is unlikely to be related to starsan in any way. Typically this is a result of
Most likely it is one of following reasons:

You bottled your beer before it was fully fermented causing it to over-ferment in the bottle
You used too much priming sugar when you bottled, causing it to over-ferment in the bottle
You have a contamination which caused the beer to over-ferment in the bottle.

